# how to add listener in android on row?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am trying to make a custom list using a custom adapter and a fragment. I am able to make a list view. But there is one problem, I have an image button and a text view in a row. I want to listen to the click event of the row, as well as the Image button's click event. In other words, I need to add a listener that will listen when the row is clicked and when the image button that is present on the row is clicked.

Here is my code:

**custom adapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (data.size() <= 0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.d("row is click","row click");

    }

    /*********
     * Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements
     *********/
    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView text;

        public ImageButton imageButton;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.station_name);

            holder.imageButton = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        if (data.size() <= 0) {
            holder.text.setText("No Data");

        } else {

            String string = (String) data.get(position);

            /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

            holder.text.setText(string);


        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/station_name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#eee345"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
     />


</LinearLayout>
```

**fragmentone.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#325633"
   >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_view">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragmentone.java**

```
public class Fragmentone  extends Fragment{

    ArrayList<String> name;
    boolean isPressed=false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        name=new ArrayList<String>();
        name.add("First Station");
        name.add("Second Station");





        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter =new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),name);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);



        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: Very simple, add click listener for your parent layout so that you can listen your over row click and add click listener for individual view in your row, remove itemonclick listener from your listview

Comment: could you please give some code

Comment: simply you can add  convertView.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out this code, if you have any trouble to understand comment

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (data.size() <= 0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /*********
     * Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements
     *********/
    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView text;

        public ImageButton imageButton;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.station_name);

            holder.imageButton = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        if (data.size() <= 0) {
            holder.text.setText("No Data");

        } else {

            String string = (String) data.get(position);

            /************ Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

            holder.text.setText(string);

        }

        // this is for overall row click
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        // this is for image button onclick
        holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        ;

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @madhu..I got the answer but how to know on which row user click .I am able to get event .but how to identity on which row user click..how to know on which row user click and on which image button user click

Comment: @user944513,You have to use position inside click listener to identified which row clicked.

Comment: @HareshChhelana the position paramenter is on getview method ..can I use that >?

Comment: You supposed to use that only, that position is the key for all items which is clicked by user

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity class where you defined listView use `setOnItemClickListener`...

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

         /** here position indicate item clicked on list,
             you can use SWITCH CASE to do things according to
             position clicked..
         */
        }                       
});
```

This you can use in Adapter class:

Row(View) listener:

```
vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Image listener:

```
holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ..I got the answer but how to know on which row user click .I am able to get event .but how to identity on which row user click

Comment: Thanks I got the answer but how to know on which row user click .I am able to get event .but how to identity on which row user click..how to know on which row user click and on which image button user click