# Edit EditText from button click inside a List Adapter Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I have a ListView and some EditTexts under it. Each row in the list has a Edit button which on click should fill up the EditTexts below the Listview. Now the issue is that i have a custom Adapter defined for the ListView. As I am inflating the layout in the Adapter class and my EditTexts are in another, how can I fill up the EditText on the click of the button inside the row of the ListView?

**EDIT**

Here is my code for the Adapter

```
public class CompleteCommentsAdapter : BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Activities.CommentListActivity commentListActivity;
        private List<Comments> dummyCommentList;
        private TextView txtUserName;
        private TextView txtCommentTime;
        private ImageView imgUserImage;
        private TextView txtCommentText;
        private ImageButton ibtnEdit;
        private ImageButton itbtnDelete;

        public CompleteCommentsAdapter(Activities.CommentListActivity commentListActivity, List<Comments> dummyCommentList)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.commentListActivity = commentListActivity;
            this.dummyCommentList = dummyCommentList;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return  dummyCommentList.Count(); }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {

                convertView = commentListActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.comment_list_row, null);
                 txtUserName = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCommenterName);
            txtCommentTime = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCommenterTime);
            imgUserImage = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgProfileUserImage);
            txtCommentText = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCommentText);
            ibtnEdit = convertView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnEdit);
            itbtnDelete = convertView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnDelete);
            }


            Comments mComments = dummyCommentList.ElementAt(position);

            txtUserName.Text = mComments.UserName;
            txtCommentTime.Text = mComments.CommentTime;



            txtCommentText.Text = mComments.CommentText;
            ibtnEdit.Click += ibtnEdit_Click;
           return convertView;
        }

        void ibtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: set onclick() method  in adapter for your edittext

Comment: @GaneshGudghe How do I access the EditText from my Adapter?

Comment: You have 2 different kinds of adapters in a listview? or 2 list views? Provide some code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @helloworld please post your adapter code

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32324203/2553431)

Comment: @GaneshGudghe have posted my code.

Comment: @DanielBo I have one listview with one associating custom adapter. The layout in which I have the ListView also has some EditTexts below it. Now in each row of the ListView I have an edit button, which when clicked should fill up text in the edittexts under the listview

Comment: you can call
` txtUserName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {}
  });`

Comment: If the Listener has to be attached to the Buttons, and not the whole row, your could just hand a reference to those Edit Texts to the Adapter. Alternatively you could build an EventBus within your app, sending the Clicked Text through different Classes.

Comment: in your adapter class

Comment: @DanielBo your solution worked.. Please post an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @DanielBo you can add your comment as an answer to close the topic

Comment: I have, sorry took me some time to realize this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Listener has to be attached to the Buttons, and not the whole row, your could just hand a reference to those Edit Texts to the Adapter. Alternatively you could build an EventBus within your app, sending the Clicked Text through different Classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
     public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                {
                    if (convertView == null)
                    {

                        convertView = commentListActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.comment_list_row, null);
                         txtUserName = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCommenterName);
                    txtCommentTime = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCommenterTime);
                    imgUserImage = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgProfileUserImage);
                    txtCommentText = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCommentText);
                    ibtnEdit = convertView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnEdit);
                    itbtnDelete = convertView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnDelete);
                    }


                    Comments mComments = dummyCommentList.ElementAt(position);

                    txtUserName.Text = mComments.UserName;
                    txtCommentTime.Text = mComments.CommentTime;

                    txtCommentTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
//do what you want here

}
                    });


                   return convertView;
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit Button:

```
 ibtnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       txtUserName.setText(""); 
       txtCommentTime.setText("");
       txtCommentText.setText("");
       }
 });
```

Comment: txtUserName is not in the same layout as the ListView